# SafeFileHandle in DLL import

Tags: c#, pinvoke

It's the first time I need to use P/Invoke to interact with device driver. In DeviceIoControl function I use SafeFileHandle for handle to the device and [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CloseHandle) says:

> If you use a SafeFileHandle, do not call CloseHandle as the CLR will close it for you.

But in C# Cookbook I found this kind signature of CloseHandle:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(SafeFileHandle hObject);
```

What's the truth?

Comment: If you want to be in charge of calling `CloseHandle` then declare your handle to be `IntPtr` instead.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I just don't want deal with IntPtrs. I was confused when stumbled across this code snippet at C# Cookbook.

Comment: If you are going to call `DeviceIoControl` then I suggest you overcome your fear of `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SafeFileHandle` internally calls `CloseHandle` in its `ReleaseHandle` method, and is designed to be used in with a `Disposable` pattern, so you don't want to manually close the handle with `CloseHandle(SafeFileHandle)` (just call the `Close` method, or `Dispose`, instead).

And as `SafeFileHandle` is `sealed`, I really don't see any point in the "`public static extern bool CloseHandle(SafeFileHandle hObject);`" signature.

---

EDIT

I just googled [your book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9fAmRzYaxFgC&pg=PT922&lpg=PT922&dq=C#%20Cookbook%20closehandle%20safefilehandle&source=bl&ots=_lYv8HiuTk&sig=tkZ7NsPJxG2zCzHkIiyyVJXF9Ik&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cocwUfmMBYqy0QWp24GIBA&redir_esc=y) and found one `CloseHandle(SafeFileHandle)` reference. As expected, it is not used, and the `SafeFileHandle` is properly closed using:

```
private void ClosePipe() 
{ 
    if (!_handle.IsInvalid) 
    { 
        _handle.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is the Win32-API function to close an open `handle`.
This function is to be used when you are using Win32-C/C++ and work with system-handles. I cannot validate the above statement a 100% about the CLR, but I guess you will be fine, not to use it.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-article on `CloseHandle`-function for Win32.

Also there is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S7) article here, which talks about the GC of the CLR.

Comment: [Digging into IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S7) - nice article and very useful for me, thanks.